# Expected distance from a random point chosen in a tetrahedron to its closest face

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> A point is chosen at random in a regular tetrahedron of height 1(so that the probability of it lying in any given region is directly proportional to the volume of that region). Find the expected value of the distance from the point to its closest face.

I have solved this question using a geometric approach that takes 6 pages of arduous mathematics, however after looking at the provided solution, they seem to have a slick approach that I just can't see the rationale behind.

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ be perpendicular distances from P to each face respectively. Let $X=\min \{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$. Then $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$ so $P(X\ge x)\propto (\frac{1}{4}-x)^3$ so the pdf of $X$ is $f(x)=k(\frac{1}{4}-x)^2$ and $E(X)=\frac{1}{16}$ follows.

($x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1$ is the geometric fact that they sum to the height of the tetrahedron.). I do not understand the $P(X\le x)\propto (\frac{1}{4}-x)^3$ part.

Comment: Is $P(X\le x)\propto (\frac{1}{4}-x)^3$ the part you are querying?

Comment: There is a geometric argument that the if you rotate the tetrahedron so the minimum distance is measured vertically, then you are restricted to a quarter of the original tetrahedron, with $f(x) \propto (\frac14-x)^2$ based on the area of horizontal cross-sections of this quarter-tetrahedron.  It is then easy calculus to find $k=192$ and so the expectation

Comment: A similar geometric argument says that to have $X \le x$, you must have your point in one of four small tetrahedra similar to such a quarter tetrahedron but with height $\frac14 - x$ rather than $\frac14$ and so volume $\propto (\frac14 -x)^3$

Comment: @Henry (1) Yes I have added that to the question (2,3) I can see your smaller triangle idea(this is how I went about it geometrically but calculated each volume manually) but how do you immediately conclude that it is proportional to the cube? Isn't the volume of a tetrahedron (1/3)(height)(base)? The base is the same when the height increases so wouldn't it be directly proportional(to the power of one, not the cube). If you can answer this, paste everything into an answer and I'll accept it. Also, is $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=1 $ superfluous?

Comment: The formula for cdf in the last sentence is still wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given hint is misleading (if you type it correctly) and the correct expression should be:
$$
P(X\le x)\propto \left(\tfrac{1}{4}\right)^3-\left(\tfrac{1}{4}-x\right)^3\quad\text{or}\quad P(X\ge x)\propto\left(\tfrac{1}{4}-x\right)^3
$$
provided that $x\le\tfrac14$. Indeed the original form implies obviously wrong conclusion that the larger is $x$ the smaller is the probability that the least distance does not exceed $x$. Besides the pdf $f(x)$ which is the derivative of $P(X\le x)$ appears to be negative.

Besides the geometrical way which was indicated in the comment one can compute the pdf in pure algebraic way. For this consider the equations:
$$
x_1,x_2,x_3\ge x,\quad x_1+x_2+x_3=1-x.\tag1
$$
Due to the last equation one of the variables ($x_3$) is uniquely determined by the other three and can be ignored provided that it satisfies the condition $x_3\ge x$. Accordingly the probability density that the value $x$ represents the least distance to a tetrahedron face is proportional to the volume of the configuration space left for $x_1,x_2$ to satisfy the conditions $(1)$.

It is easy to check that when $x$ is fixed $x_1$ has to satisfy the inequality $x_1\le1-3x$. Indeed
$$
1-x=x_1+x_2+x_3\ge x_1+2x\implies 1-3x\ge x_1.
$$
Similarly one concludes that when $x$ and $x_1$ are fixed,
$x_2$ has to satisfy $x_2\le1-2x-x_1$.

With the established boundary the volume of the configuration space can be readily computed as:
$$
V(x)=\int_x^{1-3x}dx_1\int_x^{1-2x-x_1}dx_2=8\left(\tfrac14-x\right)^2,
\quad 0\le x\le\tfrac14,
$$
and the corresponding probability density function is:
$$
f(x)=\frac{V(x)}{\int_0^{1/4}V(x)dx}=192\left(\tfrac14-x\right)^2.
$$

Comment: It should have been $P(X\ge x)$, I have corrected this in the question. Where does your algebraic way come from?

Comment: I have elaborated the algebraic way myself. I hope it does not make it less useful. Moreover it can be applied for arbitrary dimension where the geometric imagination does not help anymore.

Comment: I was asking how you arrived at your algebraic answer

Comment: I simply used the the condititions $$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge x,\ x_1+x_2+x_3=1-x$$ to determine the limits of integration. Observe that $x_3$ unambiguosly determined by $x,x_1,x_2$.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being stupid, but I don't understand what you are integrating or why. If you can explain this in your answer and how you determined the limits of integration from the conditions, I'll accept your answer

Comment: @sequencesandseries I have added some details. Hope this helps.